# how to make a field in Django only superuser editable and for other users it is read only?

Tags: django, django-models

**my model**

```
class QuestionModel(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doubt_class_id = models.ForeignKey(DoubtClasses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    conceptual_class_id = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(default='')
```

This is a question model  where a user is allowed to post new questions but i want that this answer field is only superuser editable and a normal user have only readonly access for that field, needs help i searched for possible answers but didn't get any

Comment: You can put this logic in a view permission or in a serializer/form

Comment: This really depends on how you're building your views so you might want to add your view code and potentially template code for editing/updating `QuestionModel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inherit this `mixin` to your `UpdateView`:

```
class QuestionUpdateMixin:
    """
    Question Update View Mixin
    """
    def dispatch(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_staff: # or any other condition
            self.fields = [
                'field1', 'field2', 'field3',
            ]
        else:
            self.fields = [
                'field1', 'field2',
            ]

        return super().dispatch(request, pk, *args, **kwargs)
```

And also you can pass `user` to your `form_class` and change the form fields based on user permissions in `__init__` method in your `form_class`.

You should do this logic in your `form_class` or in your `serializer`. not in your **model**.